# WebControl in a separate process stealing focus revisited

Tags: browser, focus, webbrowser-control, web-controls, twebbrowser

I need to process AJAX in my crawler and would prefer using system browser albeit I may have to change my mind. My crawler program may generally be working in background while the user can work on other stuff in other applications.

Anyhow - since WebControl leaks memory if processing JS libs that leak memory - this can cause a crawler to quickly run out of memory. (Many SO posts about this.)

So I have created a solution that uses a separate "dummy" small executable with the webcontrol that takes input/output. This is launched as a separate process by the crawler. This part seems to work great. This child process is created/destroyed as many times as needed.

However, this called process with the embedded-IE grabs focus on every page load (a least if e.g. JS code calls focus) which means if the user is doing work in e.g. Word or whatever - keyboard focus is lost.

I have already moved the embedded IE window off-screen, but I can not make it invisible in the traditional sense since then the embedded IE stops working.

I have tried to disable all parent controls before calling navigate - but it does not work for me.

Any ideas I have not tried? Maybe somehow catch a windows message that focuses webcontrol and ignore it? OR something so I can immediately refocus the earlier control that had focus?

I currently use Delphi - but this question is applicable to VB, C# .Net etc. from my earlier investigations on this matter. I will take a solution and ideas in any language.

Comment: I would ask what the goals of your application, because it sounds like some of this, if not all, may be do-able in a web-driver instead.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett what do you mean by a web-driver? Anyhow -  I have a pretty comprehensive crawler-based software used to collect lots of data and perform various site analysis. For that AJAX processing is required as well in some cases. I could switch to Chronium, but I would prefer on Windows using native IE/Edge engine and Mac using native WebView/Safari since I do not have to worry about security updates then. (+ much smaller downloadable then)

Comment: Take a look at [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676370/is-it-possible-to-read-write-a-web-page-loaded-in-ms-edge-from-a-separate-proc/48694662#48694662) for an explanation of the web driver.

Comment: Looks interesting - will check it out. However - one requirement will be I can bundle it with an installer (which I doubt) - my tool is one that is downloaded and used by people